# Swift run once with return value

Tags: swift, token, runonce

I am trying to understand Swift "run once", and there are a number of examples to be found.  But I can't seem to find one that demonstrates a return value.  I need this as I am trying to convert an ObjC function:

```
static OCNM *ocNM = nil;

@interface OCNM()

...some properties defined...

@end

@implementation OCNM

+(OCNM *) sM {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    ... instantiates ocNM
    ...set ocNM properties
   });

   return ocNM;
}
@end
```

This is called from another ObjC class via:
[OCNM sM].someOtherFunctionInOCNM

The intent here, I believe, is that once the "run once" code has been executed, any additional calls, even from other classes, will get only the existing ocNM as the return value and not run the instantiation code again.

Based on numerous different examples on-line, I have not been able to develop a Swift based class that will perform the same operations.

Being a beginner in Swift, I am hitting the hurdle of not fully understanding the run-once implementation for those examples that do NOT have return values.  Trying to modify the various examples to add an return value just makes it worse.

Current swift attempt:

```
...imports here...
var ocNM:OCNM! = nil

class OCNM:NSOBJECT{

...initialize vars here...

@objc class func sM() -> OCNM!{

    var onceToken:dispatch_once_t
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, {

    ... instantiates ocNM
        ...set ocNM properties

    })

 return ocNM;
}
```

I know that Swift has deprecated the dispatch-once implementation, but the various examples I find don't seem to clearly indicate how to replace the token code or which of the various "Void" or "()" phrases indicate what parameters are passed in, which are returned, or how the return is implemented.

This will be used in a multi-thread situation.

A hint would be certainly be appreciated.  Better yet, a "boiler-plate"/"skeleton" solution to get me started and I will fill in the rest.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.  In reviewing them (and hopefully learning from them), I realize the question is missing some significant detail. Expect an update/edit to this question in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Both `static OCNM *ocNM = nil` and `+(OCNM *)`

indicate that the property is a **class** property.

---

The Swift equivalent is pretty simple

```
class OCNM {

    static let ocNM = OCNM()
}
```

and if you want to set some other properties **once** implement `init` marked as `private`

```
class OCNM {

    let foo: String

    static let ocNM = OCNM()

    private init() {
        foo = "Hello World"
    }
}
```

For a thread-safe instance consider `actor`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you are trying to achieve a singleton instance if I understood this correctly, which was achieved in objective C with dispatch_once.

To do this in swift, you can simply do

```
static let shared: String = "Shared String"
```

or as your code stated

```
static let shared: OCNM = OCNM()
```

An example of how you can use this:

```
class OCNM { 
    static let shared: OCNM = .init()
    
    let propOne: String
    let propTwo: String
    
    private init() {
       propOne = "Ok prop one"
       propTwo = "Ok prop two"
    }
}
```

How to use this in code then

```
class UsingSharedInstance {
   init() {
      print(OCNM.shared.propOne)
   }
}
```

An article that can help

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-singleton